# Erro com exibição de dados ArrayList

Tags: java, joptionpane

Ao recuperar os dados de um arraylist por meio do comando "for", ele exibe a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: não consegui identificar onde está o erro. O que vocês acham que há de errado?

```
package listatelefonica;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<Contato>();
    String nome, telefone, email, opcao = null;

    do{
        nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Informe o nome:");
        telefone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Informe o telefone:");
        email = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Informe o email:");

        Contato contato = new Contato(nome,telefone,email);
        contatos.add(contato);
        opcao = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite N para criar um novo contato ou outra tecla para encerrar:");
    } while (opcao.toUpperCase().equals("N"));


        for (Contato umContato : contatos){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, umContato);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar o erro em forma de texto tambem, as vezes algumas pessoas quem poderiam te ajudar, podem não conseguir visualizar a imagem, por algum tipo de restrição.

Comment: O que você pretende mostrar no OptionPane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta saída está correta.

O segundo parâmetro de **`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`** será convertido para `string` e esta é a implementação padrão do `.toString()` na classe `Object` (todas as classes herdam de `Object` em Java).

Você pode criar uma implementação do método `.toString()` na classe `Contato` para alterar a saída ou então passar para o `showMessageDialog` uma `string` com a(s) informação(ções) que deseja mostrar, isso só depende do que é necessário mostrar no `OptionPane`.

Exemplos:

Mostrando só o nome do contato.

```
for (Contato umContato : contatos){ 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, umContato.getNome()); // Mostra o nome do contato
}
```

ou, mostrando todas as informações do contato (sem implementar o método `toString()`)

```
for (Contato umContato : contatos){ 
    String dados = umContato.getNome() + ", " + 
                   umContato.getTelefone() + ", " + 
                   umContato.getEmail();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dados);
}
```

ou, fazendo a implementação do `toString()`

```
public class Contato {
    // Entre outras coisas

    public String toString() {
        return this.nome + ", " + this.telefone + ", " + this.email;
    }
}
```

```
for (Contato umContato : contatos){ 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, umContato); 
}
```

Comment: Olá Jbueno! Agora entendi!! Muito obrigado pelo apoio.